# Multiple execution of trap debug

Tags: linux, bash

I was making improvements to my terminal so I've discovered in a blog (I lost that blog if you ask me, so... sorry) I can run commands before and after the execution of a command in bash, so I tried to implement it in my terminal. That blog said that before any command I can execute a command with `$ trap *commands* DEBUG` and I could assign PROMPT_COMMAND with some commands to execute them after the command output, like this:

```
$ ls
(trap_handler)
--- ls output ---
(PROMPT_COMMANDS)
```

But when I tried to use this in my computer, I get something like this:

```
$ ls
(trap_handler)
--- ls output ---
(trap_handler)
(trap_handler)
(trap_handler)
(PROMPT_COMMANDS)
(trap_handler)
(trap_handler)
(trap_handler)
```

as you can see the trap commands gets repeated three times after any command so I don't know what is happening here and how can I solve it, I've run these commands in sh and they work perfectly

Comment: What have you assigned to `$PROMPT_COMMAND` variable? And this might be useful: [Why is the DEBUG trap executed more times than expected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51557238/why-is-the-debug-trap-executed-more-times-than-expected).

Comment: I've assigned the variable to some random commands like echo Hello, pwd, date, etc. but nothing changes, also I've seen that post but it doesn't help too much, I've tried to make a "trap breaker" putting "trap - DEBUG" inside $PROMPT_COMMANDS but it just removes the last three called trap handlers

Comment: In your case `$PROMPT_COMMANDS` runs `3` commands (for example). So as you have `trap commands DEBUG` then each time a command in `$PROMPT_COMMANDS` is executed the *DEBUG* commands are executed too.

Comment: However in my `bash` shell every commands in `$PROMPT_COMMANDS` is executed after my *DEBUG command*. Not sure why you get that behavior (*you get 3 trap_handler, PROMPT_COMMANDS, and other 3 trap_handler*)

Comment: ok, some news, disabling my oh-my-bash and blesh addons I can get rid of those extra calling commads, the new behaviour of the thing is:
```
$ ls
(trap handler)
-- ls output --
(trap handler)
(PROMPT_COMMAND)
```

that's and advance but I want remove that second calling to the DEBUG trap

Comment: The second trap handler is excuted by `PROMPT_COMMAND`. You can disable the second trap handler by using `PROMPT_COMMAND='trap - DEBUG;echo something` but the problem here is that `trap DEBUG` is disabled and you have to enable again.

Comment: Oh, you're right, this is a hard challenge, when I set the trap the DEBUG trap gets executed so I need to always reset the trap, I tried to put a command that sets the trap inside the PS1 variable but the trap still gets executed when this command is called. I've used counters to only execute the trap when the modulo 2 of the counter is zero, but it doesn't work right.

Comment: Yes, it's a little bit trickier. However I tried this and seems to work properly: `PROMPT_COMMAND='countTrap=1;checkTrap;echo prompt;echo more;countTrap=0;checkTrap'` where checkTrap is a function that enables `trap "..." DEBUG` if `countTrap` is 0 and disable if is another value. **Important:** The function and variable must be in `~/.bashrc` and to disable `trap` you should use `trap '' DEBUG`. If you use `trap - DEBUG` will not work as you want.

Comment: doesn't work for me, I get the following behaviour: 
`$ ls`   
`(DEBUGtrap)`   
`--- ls output ---`   
`(DEBUGtrap)`   
`(DEBUGtrap)`   
`prompt`   
`more`